# Я сделал проверку, а мне её повторно предлагают уже 4 раз

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Я сделал сегодня с утра эту  [проверку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/497252) уже <s>4 раза</s> [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/497252).
По-моему нас теперь проверяют на выносливость психики к дежавю, а не на внимательность, а согласитесь это не уместно ;).

Это баг?

Comment: разве изменилось количество рецензентов для утверждения правки? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgE97.png - двое уже проголосовали, но почему-то недостаточно

Comment: @mymedia, что-то сбилось с id'шниками. В списке правок  id 497251 и она вполне принята: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/497251 но при этому есть точно такая же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/497252 которая не принимается, а голоса засчитываются в первую

Comment: @mymedia 4 голоса хватило, чтобы утвердить [`497251`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/497251). По крайней мере, мне так показывает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntN9o.png.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Ваш родной язык это джаваскрипт что ли?)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Нет, почему, python. Но javascript тут лучше. )